# Acceptance of USD bills

Tags: usa

I have some USD bills of 2003-2006. The money changers in India do not accept them. Some accept but offer the exchange at 10% discount than the quoted rate. Are the bills legal tender. I also have smaller denomination bills of 2009-2-13. What about their validity?

Comment: US banknotes never lose validity.

Answer (score 1):

Try a major bank. They may offer a smaller discount or sending the notes physically to their US correspondent for a fee - this may take a few weeks but may be cheaper.